# Fetch new page when user clicks a button using Svelte and Sapper

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am stuck at the part that fetch more data when user clicks a button on bottom of a page using Svelte and Sapper.

Here is the code.

```
 <script context="module">
  export function preload(page) {
    return this.fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${$count}`) // I know this is not goint to work. but when the button is clicked, I want to fetch page 2 and merge it with page 1 data, show data in ascending order(page1, page2)
    .then(res1 => {
      return res1.json()
    }).then(res2 => {
      return { 
        currentPage: res2.page,
        per_page: res2.per_page,
        notices: res2.data,
        total: res2.total,
        totalPage: res2.total_pages
      }
    })
  }
</script>

<script>
  import { count } from '../../store.js'; // export const count = writable(1); from store.js file
  export let currentPage; // 1
  export let per_page; // 6
  export let notices; 
  export let total; // 12
  export let totalPage; // 2

  const handleClick= () => {
    if ($count < totalPage) {
      count.update(n => n + 1); // update count 1 to 2 and want to deliver changed value to fetch new page
    }
  }
</script>

<main>
  <div id="container">
    <h1 class="cont-tit">Notice Board</h1>

    <div class="noti-list-wrap">
    {#each notices as notice, i}
      <ul class="noti-list">
        <li>
          <a rel=prefetch href={`notice/${notice.id}`}>
            <p class="tit">{`${notice.first_name} ${notice.last_name}`}</p>
            <hr />
            <p class="date">
              {`notice no.${i}`}
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {/each}
      <div class="show-more" on:click={handleClick}>show me more</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

At first I thought I could use $count to fetch page 2 data but import count store inside **script context="module"** won't work.

Is there a way to deliver changed value of store to function preload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to load the extra data inside `preload`. Instead, treat that as the initial data — which it is — and append to it the normal way.

This is a simplified version — it doesn't worry about error handling, race conditions, or an initial page other than `1` — to give a general idea of what I mean:

```html
<script context="module">
  export async function preload(page) {
    const res = await this.fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1');
    const data = await res.json();

    return { 
      currentPage: data.page,
      per_page: data.per_page,
      notices: data.data,
      total: data.total,
      totalPage: data.total_pages
    };
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let currentPage;
  export let per_page;
  export let notices;
  export let total;
  export let totalPage;

  const load_more = async () => {
    currentPage += 1;
    const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=' + currentPage);
    const data = await res.json();

    notices = notices.concat(data.data);
  };
</script>

<!-- other stuff -->
{#if currentPage < totalPage}
  <button on:click={load_more}>show me more</button>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the shortcut also to update the store value, like so:

```
const handleClick= () => {
    if ($count < totalPage) {
      $count = $count + 1); // update count 1 to 2 and want to deliver changed value to fetch new page
    }
  }
```

I don't see the code where you actually fetch the nth page base on `count`.

Comment: return this.fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${$count}') this part will fetch page api accoring to the value of store but $count inside this.fetch of course does not work

Comment: Probably it works if you don't use a template string but `'reqres.in/api/users?page=' + $count`

Comment: I also tried that one but got error saying "Cannot reference store value inside <script context="module">" in order words I gotta find a way  to use store inside "<script context="module">"

Comment: I don't understand why you put the preload function in a 'context' script rather then using a simple javascript file. Anyway, if the `$` shortcuts don't work, you can still import the store and subscribe to it. The handler then could do the fetch for the new page

Comment: I am following Sapper document preloading part. Code fetches api declared inside "<script context="module">" according to the document.

Comment: What about exporting a function `preloadPage(page, pageNumber = 1)` and pass the number (optionally)?

Comment: export custom function inside "<script context="module">" is not possible unless it is a data fetched using this.fetch

Comment: From all I learn about sapper, maybe it's good that I just don't use it :D